# Android APK Reverse engineering disable

Tags: android, apk

Is there any way to completely disable APK decompile and get source code back. I have developed payment app, but i need to avoid completely disable reverse engineering.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot obfuscation libraries out there.
Like proguard.
You can include it in your CI-CD pipeline and protect your code.